# Update Table in IBM DB2 Cloud from Python notebook

Tags: python, db2, cloud, ibm-cloud

I need to update the column in IBM DB2 cloud with values stored in dataframe from Python Notebook. I am able to connect to the DB2 from Python Notebook. Now I need update the one column of table in DB2 Cloud with the values stored in data frame.
Below is my code, Problem is i have 100 records in the df same has to be updated in table but with this code 10000 records are updated in the table which means 100*100. Looking for support

```py
tuple_of_tuples = tuple([tuple(x) for x in df.values])
load_db2_sql = "UPDATE schema.tablename SET Columnname = ?"
stmt = ibm_db.prepare(conn, load_db2_sql)
ibm_db.execute_many(stmt, tuple_of_tuples)
```

Comment: Consider creating a temporary table in Db2 to hold your dataframe, then use the to_sql method to populate the temporary table. Finally use a MERGE statement in Db2 to perform the required update(s).

Answer (score 0):

After a few failed attempts I came up with a different way of thinking that solved the problem you are facing.

Simple answer: using pandas `read_sql()` method read your table into a dataframe, and replace the table column values received with your new values and update by using a command `to_sql()`.

**Example:**

Assuming below is your SQL table, named `dummy_test` with schema named `TEST_SCHEMA`

```
# library versions
pandas 1.0.5
sqlachemy 1.3.17
```

```
A    B     C
  1   10   100
  2   20   200
  3   30   300
  4   40   400
  5   50   500
  6   60   600
  7   70   700
  8   80   800
  9   90   900
 10  100  1000
```

1. read this table into pandas dataframe

```
# define execution engine using sqlalchemy create_engine() 
# method with your db params

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('ibm_db_sa://{user}:{pwd}@{host}:{port}/{db};SECURITY=SSL'.format(
    user=params['username'],
    pwd=params['password'],
    host=params['hostname'],
    port=params['port'],
    db=params['database']
))
db_table = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM TEST_SCHEMA.dummy_test', engine)
```

```
# show table output
db_table
    a   b   c
0   1   10  100
1   2   20  200
2   3   30  300
3   4   40  400
4   5   50  500
5   6   60  600
6   7   70  700
7   8   80  800
8   9   90  900
9   10  100 1000
```

2. now assuming that the dataframe which values you want to use is named `df_with_values_to_update` and the column name is `A` contains the following values you want to update

```
df_with_values_to_update
    A
0   10
1   11
2   12
3   13
4   14
5   15
6   16
7   17
8   18
9   19
```

3. replace `db_table` column 'A' values with `df_with_values_to_update` column 'A' values

```
db_table['a'] = df_with_values_to_update['A']
```

4. write back to the db2 with `to_sql()` method

```
db_table.to_sql('dummy_test', engine, schema='TEST_SCHEMA', if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

You can query again the db2 from step2 to confirm the values has been replaced.